# Magento 2 : Changes In Default.xml Not Visible in All Store Views

Tags: magento2, multistore, xml

1. My online shop has 6 store views: DE, AT, GB, ES, FR, IT
2. I built very simple module that adds simple DIV element to footer
3. The DIV block is visible on all store views apart from DE and GB

Default.xml:

```
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block 
                class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                name="catchaddtocart" 
                template="XXX_YYY::initialization.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

initialization.phtml

```
<div> -- Test -- </div>
```

I tried setup:upgrade, clean cache etc.

Please advise me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cache:flush

helped. Cache:clean turned out to be too weak.